# Hidden Input field when created on the fly, isn't much useful for temporary storing strings

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, copy-paste, hidden-field

I am making a password creator script, in which I don't want to show the generated password, but only copy the generated password to clipboard.

I have script for achieving the aforementioned functionality as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="alert(generatePassword())">Generate Password</button>
        <script type="application/x-javascript">
        function generatePassword() {
            var length = 15,
                charset1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
                charset2 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@#$%^&",
                charset3 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789@#$%^&*()!+=~",
                retVal = "";
            for (var i = 0, n = charset3.length; i < length; ++i) {
                retVal += charset3.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
            }
            copyToClipboard2(retVal);
            return 'Password ready to be pasted';
        }
        const copyToClipboard2 = str => {
            const el1 = document.createElement('input');
            el1.setAttribute('type','text');
            // el1.setAttribute('type','hidden');
            el1.value = str;
            document.body.appendChild(el1);
            el1.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.body.removeChild(el1);
        };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice the commented out line, I have commented it because it is not working.

So as I have already mentioned in question, how do I make use of on-the-fly created `hidden` `input` field to temporary store the password before copying to clipboard, with the same code as above ?

Comment: What you are doing with text element (some people use textarea instead) seems just about fine. Hidden field is not a text field, so its content cannot be "selected" using `select()`, which is why you are failing to copy it to the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is duplicate because this is a more specific question, but [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) has various solutions for copying to the clipboard, including the `execCommand` approach.

Scroll down to **Complex Example: Copy to clipboard without displaying input**, which suggests fixing the Input or Textarea in the upper left corner with essentially no height, width, border, etc. so that it is not visible.